# Is there a guaranteed way to run a timer on a specific interval?

Tags: javascript, timer, queue, settimeout, setinterval

Currently, I have an async function that builds up a queue of commands, and an async function that dispatches those commands on a setInterval 1ms timer. They are both running together, which is good. The problem is - when the queue is building up it increases the time between dispatches from the normal 1-2ms to up to 150ms, which is really unacceptable for the result (animation). I also cannot run the queue build-up synchronously before the dispatching phase because the change has to be visualized immediately on the user input.

Currently, the queue build-up is happening much faster than the dispatching (although, the queue item constructor is much heavier than the dispatching function).

Is there any way to make the dispatching immediate/higher prioritized so it doesn't wait for anything else in the program?

```
dispatchTimer = setInterval(function() {
  dispatch();
}, 1);

async function constructElement {
  // making calculations
  queue.push(element);
}

async function dispatch() {
  if (transmitequeue.length > 0) {
    let element = queue.splice(0, 1)[0];
    // dispatching here  
  }
}
```

Comment: *"The problem is - when the queue is building up it increases the time between dispatches from the normal 1-2ms to up to 150ms"* I can't see the timer mechanism doing this. Is it that your callback is taking a really long time to run?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: btw, you can't run something every ms. I believe the lowest value a setInterval allows is 4ms, anything lower will just be changed to 4ms.

Comment: Also, if you're getting a queue buildup, you might be forced to "skip frames" - whatever this means in your context. If the intervals can't keep up with how much work you're sending them, you can detect that by seeing how large the queue is, and make adjustments for computers that can't keep up (yours sounds like one of such computers, so you may need to rethink this animation too - some animations are just too expensive to do smoothly)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using setInterval method to achieve that, the delay is likely from the insufficient processing capability of your system and other [probable issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays). I would suggest you use the `Window.requestAnimationFrame` ( [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) ) for animations since it would allow running statements every time the screen is repainted.

Comment: That's a great suggestion that I'm currently looking into, another similar question that's a bit out of the scope of the original one - is there a way to do the same in Node.js? It'd pretty much also an animation (synchronous with the one in the browser), but, for example, the devices animated are on a network

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for `await`, you want to await the Promise returned by your dispatching function inside the setInterval callback. I believe this will "de-prioritize" the queue build up because you'll be waiting for the dispatch Promise to resolve every ms.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why dispatching is on a constantly running interval (legacy) that is up in the main thread, but your answer made me try to change the implementation from a setInterval to a setTimeout callback inside the function itself, and it looks like it made the dispatching not to wait for the build-up, I'm not sure what's the scalability of that, and when/at what size (and if) the queue construction will come back to starving out the dispatching again, but it's certainly a big improvement.

Comment: I think if the starvation starts to happen just because of the CPU limitations I'll have to skip frames as Scotty Jamison proposed